# Mapboxgl-js expression add & max of two columns

Tags: filter, max, expression, mapbox-gl-js, addition

I am trying to get max & sum of two columns in a filter expression using MapboxGL-js. The two columns of interest may contain nulls.

Tried this for addition and it does not work (nothing shows up on the map)
["+",["to-number",['get', "col1"]],["to-number",['get', "col2"]]]

For max,I tried this and does not work either. 
["max",["to-number",['get', "col1"]],["to-number",['get', "col2"]]]

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The filter defined in mapboxgl-js is

> filter is a property at the layer level that determines which features should be rendered in a style layer.

In official mapboxgl-js example you can see that in case condition is true the feature will be rendered:

```
  "filter": ["==", "icon", symbol]
```

where "icon" is equal to symbol (a variable that is set to the selected feature's icon property).

In your example there are no conditional operation done.
In case you are trying to show the "sum" or "max" as a layer's "text-field", you should use it there and not in filter, and return string after completing your Math operations.
so it will be

```
"test-field": ["to-string", ["max",["to-number", ["get", "col1"]],["to-number", ["get", "col2"] ]]],
```

[Link to Filter Doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/filter/)

[Link to Expressions Docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#max)

Hope this helps